# Watson Text to speech not producing Audio output

Tags: ibm-watson

This is my java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    TextToSpeech textService = new TextToSpeech(IBM_WATSON_USERNAME, IBM_WATSON_PASSWORD);

    //String voice = "en-US_AllisonVoice";
    String text = "This is Just awesome And i am going to experience the effect";
    //String format = "audio/mp3";

    try {
        InputStream in = textService.synthesize(text, Voice.EN_ALLISON, AudioFormat.OGG_VORBIS)
                .execute();
        System.out.println(in.available());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

When i execute the code in eclipse, i am getting:

```
Dec 12, 2017 3:05:08 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: --> POST https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?voice=en-US_AllisonVoice&accept=audio/ogg;%20codecs%3Dvorbis http/1.1 (71-byte body)
Dec 12, 2017 3:05:09 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: <-- 200 OK https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?voice=en-US_AllisonVoice&accept=audio/ogg;%20codecs%3Dvorbis (588ms, unknown-length body)
```

Output for in.available() is: 0

Why am i not getting any audio? I can see that my text is not getting POSTED, as per the POST request.. What is that i am missing?

Comment: Can some one help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `available()` method from `InputStream` will always returns 0 because it depends on the implementation of the `InputStream`. See the [`InputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()) Javadoc.

The InputStream you get when calling `synthesize()` it's a byteStream() from the `okHttp` library.

You need to read from the `InputStream` into a file or somewhere else.
Here is a code snippet that can be used for that:

```
inputStream = textToSpeech.synthesize(/* parameters*/).execute();
outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("audio.ogg"));
int read = 0;
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
  outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
}
System.out.println("Done!");
```

**Note:** The snippet above doesn't have any `try{}catch` and it doesn't close the streams. I'll leave that to you =)